# javascript - not working for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm coding Snake Game, but I have an issue.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx');

var y = [240, 230, 220];
var x = [240, 240, 240];

var xSpeed = 0;
var ySpeed = 0;

function load() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x[p], y[p], 10, 10);
    }
}

function keyDown() {
    var key = event.keyCode; /*getting keyCode of pressed key*/
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"; /*color of rectangle*/
    switch (key) {
        case 39: //RIGHT
            xSpeed = 10;
            ySpeed = 0;
            break;
        case 37: //LEFT
            xSpeed = -10;
            ySpeed = 0;
            break;
        case 38: //UP
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = -10;
            break;
        case 40: //DOWN
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = 10;
            break;
    }
}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (x[0] >= 490) {
        xSpeed = 0;
    } else if (y[0] >= 490) {
        ySpeed = 0;
    }

    //console.clear();

    y[0] += ySpeed;
    x[0] += xSpeed;

    for (i = x.lenght; i >= 0; i--) {
        y[i] = y[i - 1];
        x[i] = x[i - 1];
        console.log(i);
    }


    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);
        //console.log("y= " + y[i]);
        //console.log("x= " + x[i]);
    }

    //console.log(xSpeed);
    //console.log(ySpeed);
}

setInterval(update, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>The Snake Game</title>
</head>
<style>
    #ctx {
        position: absolute;
        /*it can be fixed too*/
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        /*this to solve "the content will not be cut when the window is smaller than the content":*/
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>

<body onkeydown="keyDown()" onload="load()">
    <center><canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas></center>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

The for loop inside of update function is not loggin, so it looks like it's not working.

```
for (i = x.lenght; i >= 0; i--) {
    y[i] = y[i - 1];
    x[i] = x[i - 1];
    console.log(i);
}
```

I don't know what I've done wrong, but I think it's just another one stupid mistake. Please don't criticize me so much, I'm just nooby 14 y.o. programmer.
Thanks in advice,
Tomas ;-)

Comment: There seems to be a typo, `lenght`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a first sight it's just a typing mistake because you wrote `x.lenght` instead of `x.length`.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the code, but now the logging "i" is growing, but it should be reducing. Do you know why? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx');

var y = [240, 230, 220];
var x = [240, 240, 240];

var xSpeed = 0;
var ySpeed = 0;

function load() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x[p], y[p], 10, 10);
    }
}

function keyDown() {
    var key = event.keyCode; /*getting keyCode of pressed key*/
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"; /*color of rectangle*/
    
    // Prevent the snake from going in the reverse direction.
    switch (key) {
        case 39: //RIGHT
            if(xSpeed != -10) {
              xSpeed = 10;
              ySpeed = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 37: //LEFT
            if(xSpeed != 10) {
              xSpeed = -10;
              ySpeed = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 38: //UP
            if(ySpeed != 10) {
              xSpeed = 0;
              ySpeed = -10;
            }
            break;
        case 40: //DOWN
            if(ySpeed != -10) {
              xSpeed = 0;
              ySpeed = 10;
            }
            break;
    }
}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (x[0] >= 490) {
        xSpeed = 0;
    } else if (y[0] >= 490) {
        ySpeed = 0;
    }

    if((xSpeed + ySpeed) != 0) {
      for(var idx = x.length - 1; idx >= 1; idx--) {
          y[idx] = y[idx - 1];
          x[idx] = x[idx - 1];
      }
    }
    
    y[0] += ySpeed;
    x[0] += xSpeed;
    
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);
    }
}

setInterval(update, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>The Snake Game</title>
</head>
<style>
    #ctx {
        position: absolute;
        /*it can be fixed too*/
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        /*this to solve "the content will not be cut when the window is smaller than the content":*/
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>

<body onkeydown="keyDown()" onload="load()">
    <center><canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas></center>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

I really liked your code, especially for how simple it is! So I have added a slightly improved version here. These are the issues I noticed:

*Spoilers*

- In the `keyDown` function, by adding the condition to check previous speed you can prevent the snake from reversing its direction.
- In `update` function you should update the location of `x[0]` and `y[0]` only after updating the "tail" elements. Otherwise, you would not have the new location for the `x[1]` and `y[1]` element.
- Also, you might need to put an if condition for `(xSpeed + ySpeed) != 0` around the loop that updates the location of the tail elements. This would help ensure that the snake doesn't jumble up into single element before the user interacts with it.